# pandas convert column names to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

below is the dataframe (default indexes)

```
    value 1901 1902 1903 1904
44   good  12   13   14   15
70   avge  23   24   25   26
```

(the 44, 70 are indexes which i dont want)

Output should be:

```
time  good  avge
1901   12    23
1902   13    24
1903   14    25 
1904   15    26
```

I tried df.T but not quite in the required format. 
thanks a lot in advance. (can you refer some nice textbooks for this kind of operational exercises).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df.set_index('value').T
print (df)
value  good  avge
1901     12    23
1902     13    24
1903     14    25
1904     15    26
```

If need change column and index names add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('value').T.rename_axis(None,axis=1).rename_axis('time').reset_index()
print (df)
   time  good  avge
0  1901    12    23
1  1902    13    24
2  1903    14    25
3  1904    15    26
```